# Error while creating and downloading txt file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, download

I'm using the below code to download file in asp.net

```
public void DownloadFile(String fileName, String msg)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
        fileName = "Document.txt";
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
        {
            sw.Write(msg);
            sw.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;
            using (Stream download = ms)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new Byte[ms.Length];
                if (HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    int length = 0;
                    length = download.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting exception at "HttpContext.Current.Response.End();"
**HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.**

What i need to change in that code? where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Link](http://smewara.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is-on-top-of-the-call-stack/) which help you:

Use a try-catch statement to catch the exception if needed

```
 try 
    {
    }
    catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException ex)
    {
    }
    For Response.End : Invoke  HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest    method instead of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the Application_EndRequest event
    For Response.Redirect : Use an overload, Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse) that passes false for endResponse parameter to suppress the internal call to Response.End
```

---

```
// code that follows Response.Redirect is executed
Response.Redirect ("mynextpage.aspx", false);
For Server.Transfer : Use Server.Execute method to bypass abort. When Server.Execute is used, execution of code happens on the new page, post which the control returns to the initial page, just after where it was called
```

---

**Limitation/Conclusion:**

This is as designed. This exception has bad effect on Web application performance, which is why handling the scenario correctly is important.